# Sending email from a web server if it's hosted on another server

Tags: php, email

I am in the process of having a web app built. And it will link into other people's websites.

It's purpose is to be a login to a portal which will manage their customers and data.

My app will at some point send an email to their customers acting upon the clients interest.

My concern is that we won't be hosting our clients emails.

So my question is can I get my web server web app to email the customers of my clients using their email domain name?

I think all I would need is the mail server and email account details.

I think I'll be using phpemailer unless anyone can recommend anything else? Is it even possible?

I'm just looking for answers or documentation ton help me setup configure if anyone knows of any.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If they have an SPF record in their domain, they'll need to update it to include your server. Then you can send mail from their domain. If they don't have SPF, then any server can send mail from their domain.

Comment: Cheers Barmar. I will take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar says, if your clients include your servers address in their spf records (*and only use SPF for protection*) then your mail server can send messages with a from address with the clients domain.

However, there another schemes, [DKIM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), which requires a private key issued by the client. To confuse things further, there is a scheme combining DKIM and SPF called [DMARC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC).

Multiplexing the schemes and client keys via your own MTA is a formidably complex task. While @Barmar usually gives good advice, in this case I think a recommendation to simply ask the clients to include your domain in their SPF is not the best approach.

There are a lot of different choices:

- a link back to the clients MTA (for clients whom operate their own MX) which would need to support SMTPS and SMTP authentication. Possibly even vpn support
- the spf based model (for those not using DMARC or DKIM)
- sending emails from your MTA but with a a masqueraded text part in the email address, e.g.

  From: "a_user@yourclient.com" <a_user_yourclient@yourdomain.com>

  ...but with a Reply-to header pointing to the clients address, although this may impact your IPR
- just use the clients email as the from address for those without any protection scheme

It would be straightforward to handle the initial routing of the email within your applications code, but you are going to need developers who really understand how email works in practice.

Comment: Cheers for the information. As long as I know what to look out for  along with my developer, we will research what we can.  Cheers for the advice it's much appreciated.  Gives me a really good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use mailgun... Mailgun is simple to implement, you can send 10000 emails for free every month (see below) and you can send emails in behalf of clients domains. You need to add new domains to mailgun account and verify them like it's described in the documentation (see below).

Official SDK for php
https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

Domain verification documentation https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain

Pricing plan if you need to send more than 10k per month..
https://www.mailgun.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

- If your client provides you with an account in their email environment, then you can send using those credentials.  Assuming your client has a properly configured mail environment (SPF and/or DKIM and/or DMARC), then everything should be good.
- You can send from your email server directly, but your client's SPF records should include your server's IP address(es) if you don't want the email to go to spam. (Though it's possible the email will not go to spam depending on a lot of voodoo related to spam filtering and IP reputation)
- You could have your client setup a DKIM DNS entry with a public key that you generate.  Then you could have your server sign the message using DKIM and send it on behalf of the client.

Comment: Mailchimp dont need any of those to doit. You only add your email on your registered account and you send your email with your private email on the mailchimp servers